# Analyzing convergence of a simple difference equation

Tags: convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I was playing with my calculator, had an arbitrary number on the screen, then pressed <kbd>1/x</kbd> ,then <kbd>sqrt</kbd>, then <kbd>1/x</kbd>, and so forth. I noticed it converged to 1.0 after a few back-and-forths. So, it occurred to me that I did not know how to prove that such procedure converges to one for an arbitrary number different from zero.

And when playing with different function pairs such as, <kbd>$x^2$</kbd> and <kbd>$\sqrt{x}$</kbd> (this time using a computer), I notice that I get other bounded patterns.

So, my question is regarding the convergence properties of a function of the following kind:

$$
 y_{k+1}=f_{k\mod{2}}(y_k)
$$

where both $f_0$ and $f_1$ are given functions, $y_0$ is a given real number, and $k=0, 1,\ldots,\infty$.

What can be said about $y_k$ as $k\to\infty$?

Pardon my lack of knowledge! I am sure someone has looked at this!

*P.S.* Some visuals for those so inclined.

*note: migrated from mathoveflow at the request of @Anthony Quas*

[image: y0=0.5; y^2; sqrt(y)]

[image: y0=0.5; 1/y; sqrt(y)]

[image: y0=0.5; cos(y); sqrt(y)]

Comment: For your original question, start with number $a\gt 0$. Apply the operations a total of $4$ times. We get $a^{1/4}$. If we do it $4$ more times, we get $a^{1/16}$, $4$ more times gets us to $a^{1/64}$, and so on. It is a standard result, not hard to prove, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}=1$. The intermediate values, $4k+1$ iterations, or $4k+2$, or $4k+3$ therefore also give limit $1$.

Comment: Thank you, Andre. I am also interested in the more general "function" which I now believe is called a "recurrence relation" rather than a "difference equation". I'm intrigued now... how do the properties of $f_i$ relate to whether or not we converge to a fixed point, a bounded co-domain, or neither.

Comment: In the generality in which the question is put, perhaps not much can be said. The relevant function is the composition $h$ of the two given functions. If the limit is not $1$, we are likely to get the bounciness of one of your pictures. If the derivative of some compositional power of $h$ is  small, one should get convergence of such powers.